# From python script to Kernel Module

Tags: gpio, kernel

So I have a python script that emulates an ESC_KEY on pin 17.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Imports for Pins,input
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import uinput
from time import sleep

#Setup
key_events=( uinput.KEY_ESC, )
device=uinput.Device(key_events)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#MAIN
while True:
   GPIO.wait_for_edge(17,GPIO.FALLING)
   device.emit(uinput.KEY_ESC,1)
   sleep(2)
   device.emit(uinput.KEY_ESC,0)
```

Is there an "easy" way to set this up as a kernel module, or does anyone have some good documentation to create this kernel module? Do I need to rewrite it using C?

It seems as this is eating alot of resources when running in python, I'm hoping it would be less a strain on the system when run as module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel module writing would require quite a bit of effort on your part.  I'd guess a week or so of work to get a working module.

I'm not sure why Python is eating so many resources.  It should just be waiting.

I'd go for a standard userland C solution.